# Maatwebsite LARAVEL: The imported date data is not the same as the date data entered into the database

Tags: database, date-format, laravel-9, import-from-excel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm making a data import feature from excel using maatwebsite. I successfully imported the data into the database, but the year data that should have been 01/01/2022 and 31/12/2022 instead became 01/01/1970 and 01/01/1970.

this is the data that i will import to the system:
[data excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDrx9.png)

and the following is the data that was successfully imported to the database:
[data in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck8R5.png)

and this is the code for AlokasicutiImport:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Imports;
 use Carbon\Carbon;
 use App\Models\Alokasicuti;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

 class AlokasicutiImport implements ToModel
{
public function startRow(): int
{
    return 2;
}

 /**
* @param array $row
*
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
*/
public function model(array $row)
{
    if(isset($row[0]) && isset($row[2]))
    {
        if(!Alokasicuti::where('id_karyawan',$row[0])->where('id_jeniscuti',$row[2])->exists())
        {
            $data = [
                'id_karyawan'      => $row[0] ?? null,
                'id_settingalokasi'=> $row[1] ?? null,
                'id_jeniscuti'     => $row[2] ?? null,
                'durasi'           => $row[3] ?? null,
                'mode_alokasi'     => $row[4] ?? null,
                'tgl_masuk'        => Carbon::parse($row[5])->format("Y-m-d") ?? null,
                'tgl_sekarang'     => Carbon::parse($row[6])->format("Y-m-d") ?? null,
                'aktif_dari'       => Carbon::parse($row[7])->format("Y-m-d") ?? null,
                'sampai'           => Carbon::parse($row[8])->format("Y-m-d") ?? null,
            ];
            
            Alokasicuti::create($data);
        
        }else{
            Log::info('id pegawai dan tanggal absensi sudah ada');
        }
    } else{
         Log::info('Row 1 kosong');
    }
}
}
```

this is the controller that I use to import the data:

```
public function importexcel(Request $request)
{
    Excel::import(new AlokasicutiImport, request()->file('file'));
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

what are the causes sir? Please help

Comment: `Carbon::parse($row[5])->format("Y-m-d")` why the format is **Y-m-d**?

Comment: because the data type that I use is date, where is the format in my database: YYYY-MM-DD. while the format in my excel is 1/1/2000.

Answer (score 0):

The `Carbon::parse()` method cannot guess every input format correctly. In this case, you should use `Carbon::createFromFormat()` and define a specific input format.

[Carbon::createFromFormat()](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#:%7E:text=Carbon%3A%3AcreateFromFormat(%24format%2C%20%24time%2C%20%24tz)%3B)

```php
'tgl_masuk' => Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $row[5])->format('Y-m-d') ?? null,
```

The format may need to be adjusted from what is shown above if the date is being interpreted differently than shown in Excel. You should check this first.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<?php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;

      ...
      ...
     'tgl_masuk' => Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[5])->format("Y-m-d") ?? null,
      ...
```

- Excel Default takes 1970-01-01 as base date and the date format data from excel will convert into number
- use this library `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date` to convert date safely.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.